# Sort data and concatenate the result in alphabetical order with '-' separator

Tags: r, sorting, concatenation

Hi I want to get the following result: `AA-XAZ-XYZ`

```
input <- C("XYZ","XAZ","AA")
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I want to use this function in a map-reduce function. However, the sort function works fine individually, put within the mapreduce function it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a string, then here you go.

```
paste(sort(input), collapse = "-")
```

For something more readable (import the pipe operator or `%>%` beforehand):

```
input%>%
sort()%>%
paste(collapse = "-")
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. It works fine individually, but not within the function body.

Comment: Instead of `sort()`, you can use `arrange()`.